# Unir varios RData

Tags: r

Quiero unir varios .RData en un solo dataframe.
Algo como esto:

```
load(file = "fichero1.RData")
load(file = "fichero2.RData")

ficheros <- dplyr::bind_rows(fichero1, fichero2)
```

Pero si tengo muchos ficheros a unir, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo de una forma más directa?

He probado con `list.files(pattern = "*.RData")`, pero no consigo combiar `bind_rows` con `load` para poder cargarlos de golpe.

Answer (score 2):

Si los archivos tienen la misma estructura una manera de cargar todos los archivos es usando la librería `purrr` y la función `map_dfr`:

```
data <- list.files(path = "./data/", pattern = ".RData$", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map_dfr(readRDS)
```

Comment: Me da error si guardo como save(iris,file = "iris1.RData") y luego lo intento abrir. Tengo que guardarlo como saveRDS(iris, "iris1.RDS") para que funcione el código.

Comment: Al final lo saqué  
data <-list.files(path = ruta, pattern = "RData$", full.names = TRUE)  %>%
  map_df(~ get(load(file = .x)))